# How to use scenario data for projection purpose in trained models using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I trained a deep model (with normalized data) using Tensorflow and extracted .h5, now I want to use scenario data as input to pre-trained model for projection purpose. I tried

```
Model.predict(projection_data)
```

Instead of test dataset, but the outputs doesn't give an appropriate results (also scenario data have been normalized) and gives less room for interpretation. Because the exported results distributed in range of 0-1 instead of showing real changes.
I denormalized the extracted outputs and also didn't give any appropriate result.

Is there any other way to use scenario data as projection resources? Or is there any issue in data transformation?
Am I completely wrong in projection phase?

Here is the reference paper which used scenario data using regression model:
[Paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4433/13/8/1178)

Comment: There are so many cases that can solve your problem, but can't without any information about your dataset, your model, and hyperparameters. Could you inform us the factors?